# iPhoto app deleted but the photos are still showing in Media files

Tags: macbook-pro, photos, photos.app

I have deleted the iPhoto app, because I no longer use it. However, the photos (all 2000 of them) are still accessible when I try to insert media on Pages or Evernote or Keynote. I want to permanently delete all the photos from iPhoto. How can I do this? I'm running OS X 10.9.2 on my MacBook.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the App doesn't delete the Library, you need to do that separately.
Default location is at: ~/Pictures/iPhoto Library

Note: The "**~**" (tilde), in the pathname above, is your Home Folder.